# Dynamodb query a table which has hash key and limit

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in dynamo db which is like this.

```
 "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "jobcodeid",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "userid",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "TableName": "paneljobcode",
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "userid",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "jobcodeid",
                "KeyType": "RANGE"
            }
        ],
```

I want to query this table with nodejs and a retrieve data for a particular user and the user is defined in at this java script variable `req.session.user`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to query the table with hash key only.

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var table = "paneljobcode";

var params = {
    TableName : table,
    KeyConditionExpression : 'userid = :userid',
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':userid' : req.session.user
    }   
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to query item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
                null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("QueryItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Comment: I am getting this error now i have tried with scan as well as query. MultipleValidationErrors: There were 8 validation errors:
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'KeyConditionExpression' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'name' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':userid']
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'role' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':userid']
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'uuid' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':userid']

Comment: * UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'osver' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':userid']
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'islegacy' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':userid']
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'browser' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':userid']
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'date' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':userid']